# Why DVFS is not working on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, firmware, dvfs

According to the documentation https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/frequency-management.md On Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, firmware from late November 2019 onwards implements Dynamic Voltage and Frequency Scaling. I have the latest firmware on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Given below is the output from vcgencmd.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd version

Mar 26 2021 16:34:17
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version edf2e9c318863999c97c50cdb74eee235ede3af5 (clean) (release) (start_x)

I ran a test with the following python code to change the frequency to each of the available frequencies and checked the voltage and frequency through the command

**watch -n1 "vcgencmd measure_clock arm && vcgencmd measure_volts core"**

While the frequency changes as per the frequency set by the script, the voltage remains the same all the time.

Script to change frequency and governors.

```
import time
import os
import subprocess


NUM_CORE = 4
SLEEP_TIME = 30

#Sets Frequency of the available cores to freq
def set_freq(freq, num_core):

    set_freq_part1 = 'sudo sh -c "echo '
    set_freq_part2 = ' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu'
    set_freq_part3 = '/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"'

    get_freq_part1 = 'sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu'
    get_freq_part2 = '/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq'

    for core in range(num_core):
        set_freq = set_freq_part1 + str(freq) + set_freq_part2 + str(core) + set_freq_part3
    
        # print(set_freq)
        os.system(set_freq)
        print("Core {} Frequency successfully set to ...".format(core))
        get_freq = get_freq_part1 + str(core) + get_freq_part2
        os.system(get_freq)

def set_gov_userspace(num_core):
    set_gov_part1 = 'sudo sh -c "echo userspace > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu'
    set_gov_part2 = '/cpufreq/scaling_governor"'
    
    for core in range(num_core):
        set_gov = set_gov_part1 + str(core) + set_gov_part2
        os.system(set_gov)

# Sets the governor to the specified governor gov
def set_gov(gov, num_core):
    set_gov_part1 = 'sudo sh -c "echo ' + gov 
    set_gov_part2 = ' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu'
    set_gov_part3 = '/cpufreq/scaling_governor"'
    
    for core in range(num_core):
        set_gov = set_gov_part1 + set_gov_part2 + str(core) + set_gov_part3
        os.system(set_gov)
        
        
set_gov_userspace(NUM_CORE)

get_freq_str = "sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies"

# result = os.system(get_freq_str, shell=True)
result = subprocess.check_output(get_freq_str, shell=True)

#convert byte stream to string
result = result.decode("utf-8") 

print("cpu0 scaling_available_frequencies ...")
# print(result)

freq_list = result.split()

print(freq_list)

print("\n")

for freq in freq_list:
    set_freq(freq, NUM_CORE)
    # print(f"Sleeping for {SLEEP_TIME} seconds")
    print(f"Sleeping for {SLEEP_TIME} seconds")
    time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    print("\n")
    
for gov in ("conservative", "ondemand", "powersave", "performance", "schedutil"):
    print("Setting Gov to :", gov)
    set_gov(gov, NUM_CORE)
    print(f"Sleeping for {SLEEP_TIME} seconds")
    # print("Sleeping for 10 seconds")
    time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a May '21 revision to the documentation you referenced. I don't know what it said when you read it (in April '21??), but there is a boot parameter defined now: `dvfs`.

[The document](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/frequency-management.md) is a bit murky to my reading, but it indicates that setting `dvfs=1` (in `/boot/config.txt`) is required to allow the core voltages to be reduced and thereby achieve the *"significant reductions in power"* claimed there.

The Foundation also mentions *"possible system stability problems"* associated with reducing core voltages, and explains the `dvfs=1` setting is only appropriate for "headless" systems. This limitation may cause some [*"raised eyebrows"*](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/cause-raised-eyebrows), as it implies that only "headless" systems can have true [DVFS](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/dynamic-voltage-and-frequency-scaling) - "desktop" systems get only "throttling" or [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling).

And so, this is currently my *"tentative answer"*: ***Set `dvfs=1` in `/boot/config.txt`.*** After a `reboot`, you should be able to step through the various frequencies and see some differences in the core voltages.